# Javascript: == or ===?

Tags: javascript, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Hi,
This is my tiny code:

```
var domains_before_update = storage.getItem('domain_list_original');
    if(domains_before_update==null || domains_before_update=="" )
    { 
           gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("chrome://filter/content/block_and_redirect_list.html");

    }
```

Is that correct or should I be using === instead of == ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Triple equal operator is what you want there. See here: [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which "equal" operator I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Comment: Depends on if Javascript's type-casting rules would guess wrong.  What possible types can storage.getItem return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`===` checks the strict equals (without coercion) that you're used to , where `==` checks the value [after built-in coercion] equality

but as the other answer(s) noted, strict equality does not work when checking for null, use `!variable`

same as this post: [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

**edit**: clarified some of the wording thanks to the helpful comments!

Comment: @brett, 2 == "2" is true, so are you sure it checks type equality?

Comment: @hvgotcodes - I think the word from the other post 'type-converting' equality is probably the best word...

Comment: @brett, right i think you just chose the wrong word.  But 'type equality' is definitely wrong.

Comment: @brett Should be *value [after built-in coercion] equality* :-) `===` *effectively* suppresses the coercion (okay, okay, the specification defines it a little different than "suppresses the coercion" but the result is the same).

Comment: @pst - thanks for the help! assuming you don't mind, I used your comment in the post to clarify things a bit.

Comment: @Brett Lol. I don't mind. I'd up-vote, but I'm so vote-promiscuous I'm out.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it doesn't matter - and in all cases where it doesn't matter, you should use strict equality or identity, e.g. `===`.

Comment: So that would be   if(domains_before_update===null || domains_before_update==="" )   
Yes?

Comment: @Ryan, @minitech: Actually it does matter in this case: if `domains_before_update` is 0 you will get `true` for `==` and `false` for `===`. In cases where it really doesn't matter, make your own decision, considering things like readability (will you have to stop and think if you look at your code later and see `==` rather than `===` or vice versa? If so, is that a good or a bad thing?). Personally, I use `==` when it doesn't matter, but I've been through phases of using `===` or a mixture.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

Use:

```
if(!domains_before_update)
{

}
```

Comment: Not strictly, it depends on the possible return values of `getItem()` and how he wants to handle them. However, in general this will be true.

Comment: @Wesley Murch - Yes, I am assuming he wants to check for falsy values.

Comment: getitem is returning a string (a large collection of domains), I just want to see if it is empty...if it returns anything other than empty or null then I am not interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

For comparisons with null, === is required.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/325kr/

Comment: Your jsfiddle actually proves the point... The only way to distinguish undefined from null is with ===.

Comment: Yes, but obviously he wants to test if the value exists.